# Disappearing string in custom c++ exception class

Tags: c++, string, class, exception

I've written a custom exception class to deal with OLE automation errors. The what() method looks like this:

```
const char* OleException::what() const throw() {
    std::string res = std::runtime_error::what();
    LPTSTR errorText = NULL;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        hresult,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&errorText,
        0,
        NULL);
    if(NULL != errorText) {
        res = res + " - " + errorText;
        LocalFree(errorText);
    }
    //std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return res.c_str();
}
```

However, when I try to print the string it returns in my main() function, all I get is the letter "I". The weird part is: when I uncomment the second-to-last line of the method, it works just fine, i.e. I get the same message twice on my terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the pointer returned by `c_str` is invalidated the moment `what` returns, because `ret` is then no longer alive.

The solution is to make the error message a member of your exception class of type `std::string` and do the formatting at construction time, rather than in `what`. You can then safely return from `c_str`.

```
class OleException : std::runtime_error  // just guessing here
{
    std::string msg;

  public:
    OleException()
    {
        // construct msg
    }
    const char* OleException::what() const throw() { return msg.c_str(); }
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You problem is **automatic destruction of objects going out of scope**.

Your *std::string res* is local to the what() method, and you return a pointer to its internals. When you get out of the function, the local object is destructed, and you are trying to use the now dangling pointer.

When you display it from inside the what() method, there is no problem since you are displaying the string before it is destructed.

**A good solution to your problem would be to make *std::string res* a data member** of your exception class. Then as long as your exception instance is not destroyed, you can safely access the string content.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common error: You are returning a pointer to data created by a local object, which gets destroyed when leaving the function.